# AttributeError: module 'gspread' has no attribute 'open_by_key'

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to access a spreadsheet from python using gspread, but keep getting an attribute error.

`open_by_url()` and `open()` also don't work, they give an attribute error and say gspread doesn't have that module. I reinstalled gspread v3.6.0 twice, but that didn't do anything. The docs for opening a spreadsheet are [at the gspread docs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you follow the Authentication of gspread [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html). Once the auth is complete, you can verify it by using python's built in function [dir](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dir-function/).

Example:

*Service account:*

```
import gspread    
gc = gspread.service_account()
print(dir(gc))
```

*OAuth*

```
import gspread
gc = gspread.oauth()
print(dir(gc))
```

You should see the method open and open_by_url

You can either use Service Account or OAuth to access your spreadsheet.

Follow these steps for:

Service account - https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account

OAuth - https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-end-users-using-oauth-client-id

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a json file that has credentials from console.developers.google.com? If so, you can use:

```
from gspread import authorize
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scopes = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
cred = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentials.json", scopes)
gclient = authorize(cred)
sheet = gclient.open(sheet_name).worksheet(page)
```

sheet_name is the title of the spreadsheet and page is the name of the sheet found on the bottom.

Comment: Doing that I now get `ValueError: ('Unexpected credentials type', None, 'Expected', 'service_account')`

Comment: In your credentials json, what is the value for "type"? It's usually the second line and above project_id. Also, is the credential for an API Key, OAuth 2.0 Client ID or Service Account?